# Mysql Select 1 week's data from particular date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables project and project funded.

Product table is like,

```
+-----------------+
| id | date_created |
+-----------------+
| 1  | 2014-09-10 |
| 2  | 2014-05-20 |
| 3  | 2014-02-20 |
| 4  | 2014-02-20 |
+-----------------+
```

And my project_funded table is like,

```
+------------------------------+
| id | date_funded | Proj_id  |
+------------------------------+
| 1  | 2014-09-10 |      1    |
| 2  | 2014-09-11 |      1    |
| 3  | 2014-09-11 |      1    |
| 4  | 2014-09-12 |      1    |
+------------------------------+
```

Now how to get project 1's `next 1 week data count` from it's starting date.

Example, **Project_id 1** is started on 2014-09-10,

I'm in need of result like,

```
2014-09-10 => 1
2014-09-11 => 2 
2014-09-12 => 1
```

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: As @Strawberry mentioned, can you show us what you have attempted?  and a simple hint... it requires a "GROUP BY" clause in it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic query with a group by...

```
select
      pf.date_funded,
      count(*) as totalEntries
   from
      project_funded pf
   where
      pf.proj_id = 1
   group by
      pf.date_funded
   order by
      pf.date_funded
```

Now, if you only care about the 1 week after the date the project was created, this would require an additional join to the project table AND require a date range limit based on the project's create date.

```
select
      pf.date_funded,
      count(*) as totalEntries
   from
      project_funded pf
         JOIN project p
            on pf.proj_id = p.id
   where
          pf.proj_id = 1
      AND pf.date_funded >= p.date_created
      AND pf.date_funded <  DATE_ADD(p.date_created, INTERVAL 8 DAY);
   group by
      pf.date_funded
   order by
      pf.date_funded
```

In the sample above with the date, You mentioned 1 week (7 days), which could have been an INTERVAL 1 WEEK.  However, if your dates are date/time based, you really want ALL 7 days up to and inclduing 11:59:59pm.  This is why I did LESS than 8 days -- so it includes ALL the way through 7 days up to the end of the night before the 8th day.